# How to get identical file sizes for identical files residing on ext4 and NTFS partitions?

Tags: ubuntu, unix

I copy several files from a ext4 to a NTFS drive in an Ubuntu environment.

Afterwards I want to compare the sizes of each directory structures recursively. To do so, I  execute the following command on both partitions and compare afterwards the output (as a kind of safety measurement).

```
ls -1satrR --file-type --block-size=K >output.txt
```

I realize that the displayed file sizes in my output file are different between both partition types - the sizes of the directories and files are frequently bigger on the ext4 partition (for files mostly `4K`, for directories sometimes also more).

What can I do to achieve identical file sizes in the output file for both partition types?

Comment: Why do you think this is possible? As you note, they are inherently different.

Answer (score 1):

> What can I do to achieve identical file sizes in the output file for both partition types?

- Forget (skip) directories and other non-files. Their meta data size depends on the particular file system.
- Use the actual file size in octets, not KB, to avoid rounding effects.
- Make sure the size is the number of octets in the file and does not include meta data.
- Make sure that *holes* (chunks of 0 octets) do not reduce size.
- Make sure brain-dead auto-conversion is off (`\n` ⇆ `\r\n` and such).

PS: If your actual intent is to verify that the copy matches the original, you are doing it *completely wrong*.